# How to move handson table scroll bar to specific row and column..?

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying find out a method or a way by which i can move handson tables scroll bar to specific row and column.
I tried using 
selectCell (row: Number, col: Number, rows: Number, cols: Number, scrollToSelection: Boolean (Optional)) but it doesn't seems to work

here is the Fiddle link for it http://jsfiddle.net/hpfvc9bx/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  function createBigData() {
    var rows = []
      , i
      , j;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      var row = [];
      for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        row.push(Handsontable.helper.spreadsheetColumnLabel(j) + (i + 1));
      }
      rows.push(row);
    }

    return rows;
  }

  var maxed = false
    , resizeTimeout
    , availableWidth
    , availableHeight
    , $window = $(window)
    , $example1 = $('#example1');

  var calculateSize = function () {
    if(maxed) {
      var offset = $example1.offset();
      availableWidth = $window.width() - offset.left + $window.scrollLeft();
      availableHeight = $window.height() - offset.top + $window.scrollTop();
      $example1.width(availableWidth).height(availableHeight);
    }
  };
  $window.on('resize', calculateSize);

  var table = $example1.handsontable({
    data: createBigData(),
    colWidths: [55, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80], //can also be a number or a function
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    fixedColumnsLeft: 2,
    fixedRowsTop: 2,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    stretchH: 'all',
    contextMenu: true,
      afterChange : function(changes){
          console.log(changes);
      }  
  });

  $('.maximize').on('click', function () {
    maxed = !maxed;
    if(maxed) {
      calculateSize();
    }
    else {
      $example1.width(400).height(200);
    }
    $example1.handsontable('render');
  });

    $("#setSelectedRow").on('click',function(){

        console.log(table);
        table.select(9,3,12,6,true); // not working as it doesnt move scroll bar to specified column and range


    })

  function bindDumpButton() {
      $('body').on('click', 'button[name=dump]', function () {
        var dump = $(this).data('dump');
        var $container = $(dump);
        console.log('data of ' + dump, $container.handsontable('getData'));
      });
    }
  bindDumpButton();

});
```

Can anyone please help me on this...

Thanks In advance...

Answer (score 4):

You can move to specific cell using `"selectCell"` of handsontable.

You have use `table.select(...)` in `$("#setSelectedRow").on('click',function(){....`
It won't work as you are using table DOM element but you need to have "instance" of handsontable. That can be done as,

**First Way:**

```
var tblInstance = $example1.handsontable('getInstance');
```

And then apply `"selectCell()"` as

```
tblInstance.selectCell(rowNum, colNum);
```

**Second Way:**

Use `$example1.handsontable("selectCell", rowNum, colNum);`

Please refer to [**fiddle for the second way**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/hpfvc9bx/7/), in which :

```
$("#setSelectedRow").on('click',function(){        
    console.log(table);        
    $example1.handsontable("selectCell", 9, 5);  // select 9th row's 5th column

})
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: @Swapnil Navalakha, are you fine with the answer? Or any further explanation u need? Always welcome for your queries :)